# import eclipse microprofile version using maven

Tags: java, maven

I have a simple multi-module project hello-service which has multiple child maven modules(jar, war, ear). These sub modules are direct child of hello-service. I have declared following in root pom.xml

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.microprofile</groupId>
            <artifactId>microprofile</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

now in pom.xml of war module I am trying to access cdi-api like

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

but it gives error about version of cdi-api (unable to find). Not sure where am I going wrong. I have checked bom file of microprofile and it contains version of cdi-api (1.2) in it. Any clues/pointers? Given below is the error trace:

```
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ com.pjain:hello-service-war:${project.parent.version}, /home/pjain/lab/code/sample_projects/empty_ear_project/hello-service-war/pom.xml, line 11, column 14
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar is missing. @ com.pjain:hello-service-war:${project.parent.version}, /home/pjain/lab/code/sample_projects/empty_ear_project/hello-service-war/pom.xml, line 25, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar is missing. @ com.pjain:hello-service-war:${project.parent.version}, /home/pjain/lab/code/sample_projects/empty_ear_project/hello-service-war/pom.xml, line 31, column 21
[WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ com.pjain:hello-service-ejb:${project.parent.version}, /home/pjain/lab/code/sample_projects/empty_ear_project/hello-service-ejb/pom.xml, line 11, column 14
[WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ com.pjain:hello-service-common:${project.parent.version}, /home/pjain/lab/code/sample_projects/empty_ear_project/hello-service-common/pom.xml, line 9, column 12
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ com.pjain:hello-service-war:${project.parent.version}, /home/pjain/lab/code/sample_projects/empty_ear_project/hello-service-war/pom.xml, line 11, column 14
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar is missing. @ com.pjain:hello-service-war:${project.parent.version}, /home/pjain/lab/code/sample_projects/empty_ear_project/hello-service-war/pom.xml, line 25, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar is missing. @ com.pjain:hello-service-war:${project.parent.version}, /home/pjain/lab/code/sample_projects/empty_ear_project/hello-service-war/pom.xml, line 31, column 21
[WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ com.pjain:hello-service-ejb:${project.parent.version}, /home/pjain/lab/code/sample_projects/empty_ear_project/hello-service-ejb/pom.xml, line 11, column 14
[WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ com.pjain:hello-service-common:${project.parent.version}, /home/pjain/lab/code/sample_projects/empty_ear_project/hello-service-common/pom.xml, line 9, column 12
```

Comment: This works for me. There's something else going on there...

Comment: Please build on plain command and add the log output to the post...

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to change the Microprofile to the latest version. It worked for me.